# How to count the number of unique combination of numbers in a set N, whose products equal to K?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, combinations

Let *K* be the number 32, and *N* be the set of its factors.

> *K* = 32
>
> *N* = {2, 4, 8, 16}

How many unique combination of numbers are there in *N*, whose product is equal to *K* ?

The answer is 6, that is:

> [2, 16], [2, 2, 8], [2, 2, 4], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 4, 4], [4, 8]

Notice we disregard [2, 4, 2], [4, 2, 4], ... because they're already included

Comment: There's no general rule; you just count them.

Comment: @BolzWeir wow interesting. Okay thanks

Comment: @BolzWeir How are you so certain? =) (There is a formula)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: I just read the title, and I though that the OP was giving an example in his post. If we restrict our attention to the set of factors of the chosen number, then it's possible to have a formula.

Comment: @MargoEastham: The title and the text suggest different questions. Please clarify whether you're interested in the general problem indicated in the title or the more specific problem indicated in the text.

Comment: @joriki Actually I was interested in the general problem, but the set of factors was one of the examples I could think of.